# How do I pass variables generated on one button click into the function of another button click?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Visual Basic and was designing a basic calculator application on Visual Basic and I need to pass previously calculated results into the operation of my another button click. Here's what it looks like:

View of the calculator:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnMultiply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMultiply.Click
    'varialbles
    Dim decNum1 As Decimal
    Dim decNum2 As Decimal
    Dim decResult As Decimal

    'Operation
    decNum1 = txtNum1.Text
    decNum2 = txtNum2.Text
    decResult = decNum1 * decNum2

    'Output
    lblResult.Text = decResult

End Sub

Private Sub btn20perc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn20perc.Click
    Dim dec20perc As Decimal

    dec20perc = .2 * decResult <----- How do I pass it here, it gives an error obviously, but how do I solve this
End Sub
End Class
```

Now after the user multiplies two numbers I want to get the 20% of the result, but how do I pass the variable decResult to btn20perc_Click function.
What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: I replaced your `vba` tag by `vb.net` since the two languages are not the same. VBA is a much older language (essentially the pre-dot net VB6) which lives on as a macro language in things like Excel and Word.

Comment: Declare `decResult` outside of `btnMultiply_Click()`, as a Field. This way, you can access its value from any other method. See also [Decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse).

Comment: I don't understand why simple questions like this get *meaningful* upvotes!

Comment: Because people need answers even to the simplest and dumbest of questions. Not everyone is as smart as you @preciousbetine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a global variable into your form to hold the value of the first button click:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private decResult As Decimal = 0.0

    Private Sub btnMultiply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMultiply.Click
        'varialbles
        Dim decNum1 As Decimal
        Dim decNum2 As Decimal

        'Operation
        decNum1 = txtNum1.Text
        decNum2 = txtNum2.Text
        Me.decResult = decNum1 * decNum2

        'Output
        lblResult.Text = Me.decResult
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn20perc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn20perc.Click
        Dim dec20perc As Decimal
        dec20perc = .2 * Me.decResult

        'TODO - don't forget to output the result
    End Sub
End Class
```

Instead of a global variable you can also use the content of the `lblResult`:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnMultiply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMultiply.Click
        'varialbles
        Dim decNum1 As Decimal
        Dim decNum2 As Decimal
        Dim decResult As Decimal

        'Operation
        decNum1 = txtNum1.Text
        decNum2 = txtNum2.Text
        decResult = decNum1 * decNum2

        'Output
        lblResult.Text = decResult
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn20perc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn20perc.Click
        Dim dec20perc As Decimal

        If IsNumeric(lblResult.Text) Then
            dec20perc = .2 * CDec(lblResult.Text)
        End If

        'TODO - don't forget to output the result
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you please also tell me how do I display a pop up message which asks the user to enter two numbers and multiply them if they click on the Calculate 20% button before they multiply the numbers

Comment: simplest (and crudest) would be to add a `Try...Catch..` trap over the statement, if you had for example 'ABC' written in one of the textboxs (not a numeric) then it would throw an exception, so using the try..catch you could then say show a messagbox saying it wasnt correct. You can also add `If deNum1 = 0 then...` to see if the number is 0 or not.